# how to hide the points ion-slide-box on

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<ion-slide-box active-slide="index">
 <ion-slide ng-repeat="photo in photoes">
     <img ng-src="{{photo.url}}">
 </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

I don't want the slide-box show the points .
How to achieve this?

If someone can tell me？

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use

> show-pager="false"

option for [ion-slide-box](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/)

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="false" active-slide="index">
  <ion-slide ng-repeat="photo in photoes">
     <img ng-src="{{photo.url}}">  
  </ion-slide> 
</ion-slide-box>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you mean the "pager" circles which appear near the bottom center of the slider.

If so, you can hide them via CSS.

```
.slider-pager { display:none; }
```

Comment: I want to make the ion-slide-box center vertical in the ion-content,but I do not know how this can be done. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your CSS

```
.slider-pager-page:only-of-type{
    display:none;
}
```